# localStorage variable is not being saved when sharing between different parts of google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have my toggle button in my popup.js file of the google extension app.
When a user clicks on that button, I want to disable the button that I place on the every tab of user's browser.
I organize this communication through background.js file.

So here is the logic in my popup.js:

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // Get the toggle button and result container elements
    var toggleButton = document.getElementById('toggleButton');
    // Add a click event listener to the toggle button
    toggleButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Send a message to the background script
      var buttonState = !toggleButton.checked;
      console.log('toggleButtonState in popup', buttonState);
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: 'toggleButtonState' , buttonState: buttonState});
    });
  });

// Function to retrieve the toggle button state from the extension storage
function retrieveToggleButtonState(callback) {
  var buttonState = localStorage.getItem('toggleButtonState');
  console.log('Toggle button state retrieved in popup.js:', buttonState);
  callback(buttonState);
}

// Retrieve the toggle button state on popup open
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // Retrieve the toggle button state and apply it
  retrieveToggleButtonState(function(buttonState) {
    console.log('retrieveToggleButtonState in popup.js', buttonState );
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ type: 'toggleButtonState' , buttonState: buttonState});
  });
});
```

When a user clicks on toggle button, I pass that to my background script.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.type === 'toggleButtonState') {
    console.log('toggleButtonState in background', request.buttonState)
    chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) { // Query all tabs by removing the 'currentWindow' constraint
      tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { type: 'toggleButtonState', buttonState: request.buttonState });
      });
    });
  }
});
```

From the background.js I pass my message further to bottom_button.js, where I implement my button, which I want show/hide, depending on the toggle in the popup:

```
    // Function to handle the toggle button message from the background script
function handleToggleButtonMessage(showButton) {
  if (showButton) {
    button.style.display = 'block'; // Show the button
  } else {
    button.style.display = 'none'; // Hide the button
  }
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.type === 'toggleButtonState') {
    // Handle the toggle button state change
    var buttonState = request.buttonState;
    handleToggleButtonMessage(buttonState);
    console.log('toggleButtonState in bottom_button', buttonState);

    // Save the updated toggle button state to local storage
    localStorage.setItem('toggleButtonState', buttonState);
  }
});

// Retrieve the initial toggle button state from localStorage
var initialButtonState = localStorage.getItem('toggleButtonState');
console.log('initialButtonState', initialButtonState);

// Set the initial state of the toggle button
handleToggleButtonMessage(initialButtonState);
```

I see that when I toggle the button on one tab, the button is not shown on another tab. However, the `localStorage.getItem('toggleButtonState')` is null when I open the popup on another tab. It seems that the `localStorage.getItem('toggleButtonState')` initializes with null earlier than the value being retrieved from the storage.

Please point me to the right direction to find a solution.

Comment: Don't use `localStorage` use [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/).

Comment: Okay, could you please explain the reason, @Titus?

Comment: The reason is the problem that you've described. Inside the content script you'll get the `localStorage` of the domain the script is injected in not the one of the extension.